# Doctrine query + LIKE expression

Tags: doctrine-orm, sql-like, dql

I have problems to create a Doctrine Query with LIKE Expression:

**QUERY:**

```php
$dql    = "SELECT u FROM Users u JOIN u.group g WHERE g.name LIKE lower('ADMIN')";
$query  = $em->createQuery($dql);
$result = $query->getResult();
```

**ERROR:**

```
QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 147: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_STRING, got 'lower'
```

LOWER was just an example, I need to use other functions in LIKE
EXPRESSION, for example, unnacent...

How can I change Like Expression to support function on both sides?

Example: `LOWER(unaccent(u.login)) LIKE LOWER(unaccent('ADMIN'))`

Comment: Did you try with `LOWER` instead of `lower` ? (as it's in the [doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions))

Comment: Same error:    QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 154: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_STRING, got 'LOWER'

Comment: Can you use QueryBuilder instead of DQL? [It seems to be ok with it](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-334).

Comment: Doesn't work. Same problem, LIKE expect STRING and not FUNCTION...

Answer (score 3):

The like string needs to have % signs. If you want something that starts with ADMIN then you would write ADMIN% if you want something that ends with ADMIN you would write %ADMIN and finally if you want it to contain ADMIN then it would be %ADMIN%.

Maybe to return a string you can use the CONCAT function of doctrine or you can do it via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with QueryBuilder and there doesn't seem to be a solution.  The second parameter will not take a function, so I would suggest switching the parameters around:

```
$dql    = "SELECT u FROM Users u JOIN u.group g WHERE UPPER(g.name) LIKE 'ADMIN'";
```