# How to add LIKE expression in QueryBuilder for a column without alias

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, query-builder, sql-like

I am developing a list with filter in Yii1 and doctrine2.
I will skip unnecessary information like controller-action codes and just explain the problem.

This is my queryBuilder object:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('asset')
            ->select("asset.id, 
                CONCAT(user.firstName, CONCAT(' ',user.lastName)) assignedBy, 
                asset.createdAt, asset.serial, asset.brand, asset.model,
                assetType.name assetTypeName, 
                CONCAT(assigned.firstName,CONCAT(' ',assigned.lastName)) assignedTo, 
                asset.status, location.name locationName")
            ->leftJoin('asset.user', 'user')
            ->leftJoin('asset.assigned', 'assigned')
            ->leftJoin('asset.location', 'location')
            ->leftJoin('asset.assetType', 'assetType');
```

As you may noticed, I have two aggregated columns(assignedBy, AssignedTo) without alias(If I could, I would write **user.assignedBy** in the first one and same for the later one, **but** it is not acceptable in sql since they do not belong to any actual table).

Later on, when form submitted in client, I need to add like expressions for them. (It is kind of auto generated query, but for simplification I will mention the function in charge of it only and skip the rest)
this function works with an array from $_REQUEST. I put it here as guide:

```
array (size=9)
  'assignedBy' => string 'mojtaba' (length=7)
  'createdAt' => string '' (length=0)
  'serial' => string '' (length=0)
  'brand' => string '' (length=0)
  'model' => string '' (length=0)
  'assetType' => string '' (length=0)
  'assigned' => string '' (length=0)
  'location' => string '' (length=0)
  'status' => string '' (length=0)
```

and the function:

```
    /**
     * @return $this
     * @throws \CException
     */
    public function applyFilter()
    {
        // it is the array came from $_REQUEST, I mentioned it above.
        if (isset($_REQUEST[$this->getFilterKey()])) {
            $or = $this->getQueryBuilder()->expr()->orX();

            foreach ($_REQUEST[$this->getFilterKey()] as $key => $val) {
                if ($val) {
                    $term = $key;
                    $or->add($this->getQueryBuilder()->expr()->like($term, ":" . $key));
                    $this->getQueryBuilder()->setParameters(array($key => "%" . $val . "%"));
                }
            }
            ($or->getParts()) ? $this->getQueryBuilder()->andWhere($or) : "";
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

for all the columns with alias in this query, there is absolutely no problem but for these two, I get this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 186: Error: Expected '.' or '(', got 'assignedBy'
```

and the real error occurs in here:

```
vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(2541): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->LikeExpression()
```

I have read that QueryBuilder does not support functions in Like expression here:
[Doctrine query + LIKE expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916797/doctrine-query-like-expression), but It is a different matter, I do not need to use functions, I want to use a column without alias in queryBuilder alias expression and I get this error, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @cale_b Is not it better to save the first part (PHP Doctrine2:) of the title you have removed?
I think it helps the question to be more verbose in search?

Comment: No, because that is covered in the tags.  On SO, you typically do not want to repeat the tags in the title.